# Síntesis de un decodificador en puertas lógicas ideales

Tags: verilog

Tengo un decodificador definido en verilog como

```
module mi_decodificador(
    entrada [3:0] in
    salida reg[19:0] out
    );

    always@(*) begin
        caso (in)
            4'd0: out= 20'd114912;
            4'd1: out= 20'd114912;
            4'd2: out= 20'd180324;
            4'd3: out= 20'd409644;
            4'd4: out= 20'd917535;
            4'd5: out= 20'd395532;
            4'd6: out= 20'd137988;
            4'd7: out= 20'd16128;
            4'd8: out= 20'd16128;
            4'd9: out= 20'd16128;
            4'd10: out= 20'd137988;
            4'd11: out= 20'd395532;
            4'd12: out= 20'd917535;
            4'd13: out= 20'd409644;
            4'd14: out= 20'd180324;
            4'd15: out= 20'd114912;
        endcase
    fin

endmodule
```

Quiero sintetizar esto usando sólo celdas lógicas ideales AND, OR, NAND, XOR y NOT. Hasta ahora he intentado tres enfoques con poco éxito:
i) Funciones POS/SOP form del módulo sympy (sin éxito porque sólo se utilizan AND, OR y NOT).
ii) Síntesis de Vivado (sin éxito porque el diseño se sintetiza utilizando LUT).
iii) Usando el sintetizador de yosys (sin éxito porque, aparentemente, debería escribir un archivo .lib "de juguete" con las descripciones físicas de las celdas que quiero utilizar, lo que me parece demasiado trabajo para lo que quiero conseguir, que es mucho más simple).

¿Existe algún enfoque mejor para este problema?

Gracias.

Comment: No entiendo el problema: ¿qué diferencia hace la sintesis en el resultado? Además ¿por qué no usar una simple ROM de 16x20?

Comment: El código que publicas tiene numerosos errores de sintaxis. ¿Podrías publicar una versión compilable?